# What name is given to this order relation on a monoid obtained by altering the definition of conjugate elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, terminology, monoid

Two elements $x$ and $y$ in a group are said to be *conjugate* if and only if there exists $t$ satisfying $y = txt^{-1}$. This defines an equivalence relation on the group under question. A variant on this definition is sometimes useful in the context of monoids. Let's say that an element $x$ of a monoid is "conjugate-less-than-or-equal-to" $y$ if and only if there exist elements $s$ and $t$ such that $ts=1$ and $y = txs$. This relation is always a preorder.

> **Question.** Does this relation have a name, and/or is it studied anywhere?

Comment: I'm not familiar with a name for this notion, but I might describe it as retract conjugacy? I'm not sure about the order relation, but we can make the observation that for a general category a retract induces a surjective morphism on endomorphism monoids via this same formula.